# Error when make "make install" PHP WebDav

Tags: linux, php, fedora, webdav, make

I'm having issues install [PHP WebDAV](http://php-webdav.pureftpd.org/project/php-webdav) onto Fedora8 - after downloading and running make install I get the following errors:

```
[root@ip-18-192-114-35 dav]# make install
/bin/sh /tmp/dav/libtool --mode=compile gcc  -I. -I/tmp/dav -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/dav/include -I/tmp/dav/main -I/tmp/dav -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /tmp/dav/dav.c -o dav.lo
 gcc -I. -I/tmp/dav -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/dav/include -I/tmp/dav/main -I/tmp/dav -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /tmp/dav/dav.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/dav.o
/tmp/dav/dav.c:21:23: error: ne_socket.h: No such file or directory
/tmp/dav/dav.c:22:24: error: ne_session.h: No such file or directory
/tmp/dav/dav.c:23:22: error: ne_utils.h: No such file or directory
/tmp/dav/dav.c:24:21: error: ne_auth.h: No such file or directory
/tmp/dav/dav.c:25:22: error: ne_basic.h: No such file or directory
/tmp/dav/dav.c:26:20: error: ne_207.h: No such file or directory
/tmp/dav/dav.c:35: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'ne_session'
/tmp/dav/dav.c: In function 'dav_destructor_dav_session':
/tmp/dav/dav.c:152: error: 'DavSession' has no member named 'sess'
/tmp/dav/dav.c:153: error: 'DavSession' has no member named 'sess'
/tmp/dav/dav.c:155: error: 'DavSession' has no member named 'base_uri_path'
/tmp/dav/dav.c:156: error: 'DavSession' has no member named 'user_name'
/tmp/dav/dav.c:157: error: 'DavSession' has no member named 'user_password'
/tmp/dav/dav.c:158: error: 'DavSession' has no member named 'sess'
/tmp/dav/dav.c: In function 'cb_dav_auth':
/tmp/dav/dav.c:194: error: 'DavSession' has no member named 'user_name'
/tmp/dav/dav.c:194: error: 'NE_ABUFSIZ' undeclared (first use in this function)
/tmp/dav/dav.c:194: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
/tmp/dav/dav.c:194: error: for each function it appears in.)
/tmp/dav/dav.c:195: error: 'DavSession' has no member named 'user_password'
/tmp/dav/dav.c: In function 'zif_webdav_connect':
/tmp/dav/dav.c:212: error: 'ne_session' undeclared (first use in this function)
/tmp/dav/dav.c:212: error: 'sess' undeclared (first use in this function)
/tmp/dav/dav.c:213: error: 'ne_uri' undeclared (first use in this function)
/tmp/dav/dav.c:213: error: expected ';' before 'uri'
/tmp/dav/dav.c:215: error: 'uri' undeclared (first use in this function)
/tmp/dav/dav.c:259: error: 'DavSession' has no member named 'base_uri_path'
/tmp/dav/dav.c:260: error: 'DavSession' has no member named 'base_uri_path_len'
/tmp/dav/dav.c:262: error: 'DavSession' has no member named 'user_name'
/tmp/dav/dav.c:264: error: 'DavSession' has no member named 'user_name'
/tmp/dav/dav.c:267: error: 'DavSession' has no member named 'user_password'
/tmp/dav/dav.c:269: error: 'DavSession' has no member named 'user_password'
/tmp/dav/dav.c:271: error: 'DavSession' has no member named 'sess'
/tmp/dav/dav.c: In function 'get_full_uri':
/tmp/dav/dav.c:304: error: 'DavSession' has no member named 'base_uri_path_len'
/tmp/dav/dav.c:307: error: 'DavSession' has no member named 'base_uri_path_len'
/tmp/dav/dav.c:313: error: 'DavSession' has no member named 'base_uri_path'
/tmp/dav/dav.c:313: error: 'DavSession' has no member named 'base_uri_path_len'
/tmp/dav/dav.c:314: error: 'DavSession' has no member named 'base_uri_path_len'
/tmp/dav/dav.c: In function 'zif_webdav_get':
/tmp/dav/dav.c:329: error: 'ne_session' undeclared (first use in this function)
/tmp/dav/dav.c:329: error: 'sess' undeclared (first use in this function)
/tmp/dav/dav.c:330: error: 'ne_request' undeclared (first use in this function)
/tmp/dav/dav.c:330: error: 'req' undeclared (first use in this function)
/tmp/dav/dav.c:348: error: 'DavSession' has no member named 'sess'
/tmp/dav/dav.c:354: error: 'ne_accept_2xx' undeclared (first use in this function)
/tmp/dav/dav.c:359: error: 'NE_OK' undeclared (first use in this function)
/tmp/dav/dav.c:359: error: invalid type argument of '->'
/tmp/dav/dav.c: In function 'zif_webdav_put':
/tmp/dav/dav.c:377: error: 'ne_session' undeclared (first use in this function)
/tmp/dav/dav.c:377: error: 'sess' undeclared (first use in this function)
/tmp/dav/dav.c:378: error: 'ne_request' undeclared (first use in this function)
/tmp/dav/dav.c:378: error: 'req' undeclared (first use in this function)
/tmp/dav/dav.c:396: error: 'DavSession' has no member named 'sess'
/tmp/dav/dav.c:405: error: 'NE_OK' undeclared (first use in this function)
/tmp/dav/dav.c:405: error: invalid type argument of '->'
/tmp/dav/dav.c: In function 'zif_webdav_delete':
/tmp/dav/dav.c:422: error: 'ne_session' undeclared (first use in this function)
/tmp/dav/dav.c:422: error: 'sess' undeclared (first use in this function)
/tmp/dav/dav.c:423: error: 'ne_request' undeclared (first use in this function)
/tmp/dav/dav.c:423: error: 'req' undeclared (first use in this function)
/tmp/dav/dav.c:441: error: 'DavSession' has no member named 'sess'
/tmp/dav/dav.c:448: error: 'NE_OK' undeclared (first use in this function)
/tmp/dav/dav.c:448: error: invalid type argument of '->'
/tmp/dav/dav.c: In function 'zif_webdav_mkcol':
/tmp/dav/dav.c:465: error: 'ne_session' undeclared (first use in this function)
/tmp/dav/dav.c:465: error: 'sess' undeclared (first use in this function)
/tmp/dav/dav.c:466: error: 'ne_request' undeclared (first use in this function)
/tmp/dav/dav.c:466: error: 'req' undeclared (first use in this function)
/tmp/dav/dav.c:484: error: 'DavSession' has no member named 'sess'
/tmp/dav/dav.c:491: error: 'NE_OK' undeclared (first use in this function)
/tmp/dav/dav.c:491: error: invalid type argument of '->'
/tmp/dav/dav.c: In function 'zif_webdav_copy':
/tmp/dav/dav.c:510: error: 'ne_session' undeclared (first use in this function)
/tmp/dav/dav.c:510: error: 'sess' undeclared (first use in this function)
/tmp/dav/dav.c:511: error: 'ne_request' undeclared (first use in this function)
/tmp/dav/dav.c:511: error: 'req' undeclared (first use in this function)
/tmp/dav/dav.c:539: error: 'DavSession' has no member named 'sess'
/tmp/dav/dav.c:550: error: 'NE_DEPTH_INFINITE' undeclared (first use in this function)
/tmp/dav/dav.c:550: error: 'NE_DEPTH_ZERO' undeclared (first use in this function)
/tmp/dav/dav.c:554: error: 'NE_OK' undeclared (first use in this function)
/tmp/dav/dav.c:554: error: invalid type argument of '->'
/tmp/dav/dav.c: In function 'zif_webdav_move':
/tmp/dav/dav.c:573: error: 'ne_session' undeclared (first use in this function)
/tmp/dav/dav.c:573: error: 'sess' undeclared (first use in this function)
/tmp/dav/dav.c:574: error: 'ne_request' undeclared (first use in this function)
/tmp/dav/dav.c:574: error: 'req' undeclared (first use in this function)
/tmp/dav/dav.c:598: error: 'DavSession' has no member named 'sess'
/tmp/dav/dav.c:611: error: 'NE_OK' undeclared (first use in this function)
/tmp/dav/dav.c:611: error: invalid type argument of '->'
make: *** [dav.lo] Error 1
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are missing the required header files.

Did you do this (from provided [link](http://php-webdav.pureftpd.org/project/php-webdav))?

```
This extension requires the Neon library and the related header files.
```

You need to install the `neon` library from source or install the devel package if installing from RPM. If you think the library is already installed, you can check by locating the header files shown in the error message.

Comment: yum install neon-devel solved the issue. Thanks so much!